# How to get a list of all email of all the users in an exchange server?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

What is the best way to get a list of all email(TO email address and the body) of all the users in an exchange server?

I realize this might seem to be absurd requirement, but I need it to run some analysis.

I looked at Exchange web services which seem to give only access to the logged in user data, is that true?
I looked at powershell access to exchange, but could not figure the command to do that.

Comment: I suggest a quick search on terms like `exchange powershell list email addresses`. The results should help you quite a long way, I'd believe. If you still are having issues, please update the question with the new attempts as well.

Comment: @robert.westerlund That is giving me all email address in Mailboxes, I want all the email sent to each other.

Comment: Okay, I missread your question. I have no idea how to do that but would resort to the same internet searches that you have probably already done. Perhaps `Search-Mailbox` might work? However, I do suggest looking into the legality of such an operation in the country you reside, if you haven't already. In some countries this might not be legal, in order to protect the privacy of individuals.